# Connect pod to local process with minikube

Tags: kubernetes, apache-zookeeper, minikube

I am new to kubernetes and trying to throw together a quick learning project, however I am confused on how to connect a pod to a local service.

I am storing some config in a ZooKeeper instance that I am running on my host machine, and am trying to connect a pod to it to grab config.

However I cannot get it to work, I've tried the magic "10.0.2.2" that I've read about, but that did not work. I also tried creating a service and endpoint, but again to no avail. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Also, for background I'm using minikube on macOS with the hyperkit vm-driver.

Comment: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/get-shell-running-container/

Comment: You should be able to just hit your host machine's IP from within the pod, instead of the magic endpoint. Minikube doesn't configure the magic 10.0.2.2 (that's a VirtualBox default). I've never used hyperkit, so don't know how that configures networking.

Comment: @MarcinRomaszewicz that did the trick, which in retrospect makes a lot of sense, thanks!